# IF AND ELSE to turn decimal values into string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using MSSQL and need to write a query to have:

```
RESULT
------
abc
```

For example, if I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE A (a int)
```

..and attempt to use:

```
SELECT IF a > 20 THEN 'abc' 
       ELSE 'def' 
       END 
  FROM A
```

But it does not work with SQL. How is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN a > 20 THEN 'abc' 
         ELSE 'def' 
    END 
FROM A
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select case when A.a > 20 then 'abc' else 'def' end 
  from A
```

---- added a week later ----

Geez, sorry to not have formatted my SQL, it was just a quick response! :)

```
SELECT    CASE 
              WHEN A.a > 20 THEN 'abc' 
              ELSE 'def' 
          END AS derived 
FROM      A
```